# Lags when navigating vc-root-diff buffer

Tags: git, vc-mode

When I move around the buffer `*vc-diff*` from `vc-root-diff` I experience lags.

GNU Emacs 27.1 (build 1, x86_64-pc-cygwin) of 2020-10-29.

With `procmon` I detected lots of:

```
C:\opt\cygwin64\bin\git.exe --no-pager ls-files -z --full-name -- application.yml
C:\opt\cygwin64\bin\git.exe --no-pager cat-file blob 4f6e63900c275c7c53519ac0a2f6bc1cdd65abf8:application.yml
```

that generated for each new file in diff...

It is from `vc-git-find-revision`.

Even though I enabled debugging on entering that function Emacs didn't stop there, so I cannot get stack trace which hook is responsible to process spawning.

I want to disable that "feature".

**UPDATE 2023-04-10** [Bug report: Emacs keeps opening related file from vc-diff buffer](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=62749)

Answer (score 2):

I already had an issue with hunk refinement, that fixed by:

```
;; Since 27.1 it is enabled during font-lock. Need to disable explicitly.
(setq diff-refine nil)
```

So I checked `/usr/share/emacs/27.1/lisp/vc/diff-mode.el.gz` again and found:

```
(defcustom diff-font-lock-syntax t)
```

So basically Emacs opens file behind in order to build proper syntax highlighting. That triggers slow VC commands. Yes, Cygwin is slow on `fork()`.

Solution:

```
(setq diff-font-lock-syntax 'hunk-only)
```

I think it is a bug that Emacs tries to do `vc-git-find-revision` behind the scene when `diff-font-lock-syntax` it `t`. Exhausted to report it ((