# Modern Emacs keeps opening related file from vc-diff buffer

Tags: git, ediff, vc-mode

Initially I opened [Lags when navigating vc-root-diff buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/61760/lags-when-navigating-vc-root-diff-buffer/) and the cause of slowness was Emacs opening referenced files by diff.

Back then I used Emacs 27.1. Now I'm on Emacs 28.2 and previous solution:

```
(setq diff-font-lock-syntax 'nil)
```

doesn't work:

- I experience delay of Emacs opening files in the background
- later I end with lots of buffers with files I personally never opened but Emacs opened them for me, so I spend minutes closing tons of files, they pollute history of recent files (I don't care about robotic opened file, I need only human origin).

**UPDATE 2023-04-10** [Bug report: Emacs keeps opening related file from vc-diff buffer](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=62749)

Comment: Irrelevant to the question: you don't have to `quote` a `nil`.

Comment: Seems they are equal: `(eq nil 'nil)` is `t`... `quote` is a macro so the end result could be magical.

Comment: "*`quote` is a macro*" --- `quote` is a *special form*.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a candidate for `M-x report-emacs-bug`, if you don't get a helpful answer here. On the other hand, you say "Modern Emacs", and there's an Emacs with that name which differs from GNU Emacs. Maybe there's a different way to report a bug there, if you meant that particular Emacs.

Comment: Emacs is stock GNU Emacs in Cygwin. Probably need to file a bug report. I thought other people struggle with the issue, like it is a common problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug report https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=62749

The culprit is:

```
(which-func-mode 1)
```

When the cursor moves through the hunks of *VC diff* the mode automatically opens corresponding file, causing Emacs to hang a lot in Cygwin env ((